# xcode - Copy asset catalogue to another project

Tags: xcode

I have one Xcode project in which I've completely set up the asset catalogue, and I want to use the same asset catalogue in another project. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First create the (empty) asset catalogue in your new project, In your new project click the target, and in the editor under 'App icons' click the button for 'Use asset catalogue'. Make sure the 'also use for launch images' is checked.

Now go out to the finder, and open two windows - one with your new project and one with the source project from which you're copying the asset catalogue.

In the source project, find the `Images.xcassets` folder. Option-drag it into the new project folder so that it will replace the empty one you just created in Xcode.

Comment: Asset Catalog is just a folder named blahblahblah.xcassets, so you just copy that folder to your project (added to Target) and you're good to go

Comment: **Option-drag** - this solved my problem of how to copy between different *.xcassets (rather than move). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me like this:

**Drag the contents of the "Assets.xcassets" folder of the source project into the Assets pane of the new project.**

(the only small problem, is that it will create a duplicate set for the app icon, just delete it. Or just thrown away the empty app icon set of the destination project be before importing).